# Why won't it let me change the value of a property of an object?

Tags: inform7

I have this code and the commented line breaks it.  What have a done wrong here?  I know I can just say pen can be red, green, or blue; but I want to use the value color or something like it to share the property with other objects.

```
NicePlace is a room. "Its a pretty nice place."

A color is a kind of value.
The colors are red, green, blue.

A pen is a kind of thing.
A pen has a color called pencolor.

A coolpen is a pen.
The pencolor of coolpen is red.
[Now the pencolor of coolpen is blue.]

There is a coolpen in NicePlace.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phrases like "now ..." must be placed in rules, otherwise Inform doesn't know when to run them. So try this:

```
When play begins:
    Now the pencolor of coolpen is blue.
```

Comment: Turns out there are a lot more rule syntax's that are now making IF7 a lot easier.  Thanks for mentioning rules.

Comment: I think it's always been that way. There are declarations to define the world, rules to control what happens when, and phrases to make changes to the world and say stuff. If you're used to other languages you may be interested in [The Inform 7 Programmer's Manual](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/50GD/assignments/Inform_7_for_Programmers.pdf).